# unable to call the same javascript function onfocusout="getPrize()" dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;
var j=0;
    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="eway_bill_no2' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_name' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_hsn' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="quantity'+j+'" name="quantity' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="price'+j+'" onfocusout="getsubTotal2()" name="amount' + counter + '" id="page"/></td>';        
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="subtotal'+j+'" name="subtotal' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="discount'+j+'" onfocusout="getPrice2()" name="discount' + counter + '"/></td>';        
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="total'+j+'" name="total' + counter + '"/></td>';                               

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger "  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;
        j++;

        
    });
/*here we are using this to add row in this auto calculation of prize and discount is in below functions*/

getsubTotal2 = function() {

var k=0;

            var numVal3 = Number(document.getElementById("quantity"+k).value);
            var numVal4 = Number(document.getElementById("price"+k).value);
            var totalValue2 = (numVal3 * numVal4)
            document.getElementById("subtotal"+k).value = totalValue2.toFixed(2);
            k++; 
        

}
      getPrice2 = function() {
      var l=0;
            var numVal1 = Number(document.getElementById("subtotal"+l).value);
            var numVal2 = Number(document.getElementById("discount"+l).value) / 100;
            var totalValue = numVal1 - (numVal1 * numVal2)
            document.getElementById("total"+l).value = totalValue.toFixed(2);
            l++;
            
}

/*the function is getting called only once help me with this i am new here
```

its just an GST calculating form just want auto calculation of quantity*amount and amount-discount=total;

help with this

/*the function is getting called only once help me with this i am new here

its just an GST calculating form just want auto calculation of quantity*amount and amount-discount=total;

help with this
/*the function is getting called only once help me with this i am new here

its just an GST calculating form just want auto calculation of quantity*amount and amount-discount=total;

help with this

Comment: Your code is incomplete, but it *looks like* `getPrice2 = function...` is defined with doc.ready - if that's the case the it's *scoped* to doc.ready only and can't be used from HTML `onfocusout=` - you need to make the function global or just use a jquery event handler instead of the outdated html event

Comment: no usage of doc.ready is been made and the function itself is global totally 3 different functions one usinf #addnew to add row every time onclick and other 2 functions getsubtotal() and getPrize() at onfocusout event but its working for only one call when second row is added the other 2 functions arent getting called

Comment: Well, you always reset `l=0` and `k=0` each time you call the functions so it will only ever work on the first row.   If you want it only on the "active" row, then `onfocusout="getPrice2(' + j + ')"` and `getPrice2 = function(l) { ...` and remove `l=0;l++`

Comment: @freedomn-m thank you so much finally got it done just declared globally:)